# What distribution has the p.d.f. of form $\frac{e^{-b \cdot x} \cdot x^c}{1 + e^{-k \cdot (x+a)}}$ for $x >0$ and parameters $b > 0, k > 0, c > 0$?

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

In my work I met the p.d.f. of form $$p(x) \propto \frac{e^{-b \cdot x} \cdot x^c}{1 + e^{-k \cdot (x+a)}}$$ with support $x \in [0, +\infty)$ and positive parameters $b > 0, k > 0, c > 0$.
It is known that integral $\int_0^{+\infty} p(x) < \infty$. Hope, $p(x)$ is for  transformation of some classical distribution, so I can easily sample from $p(x)$.

If visualized, $p(x)$ is very similar to belong to the Gamma distribution family. E.g., for parameter values $a=1.0$, $b=1.7$, $c=3.0$, and $k=2.3$ function $p(x)$ is graphed below:

[image: p.d.f. for a=1.0, b=1.7, c=3.0, and k=2.3]

Comment: What are the possible values of $a$? Could it be negative?  Is your principal concern to sample from this distribution?

Comment: Thanks for your response! $a$ is real, and so it may be negative. You're right, my target is to sample from $p(x)$.

Comment: I wondered about the sign of $a$ because when it's not too negative, rejection sampling from the Gamma distribution looks like an attractive option. But with a bit of algebraic work, it looks like rejection sampling might be effective for a wide range of the parameters--maybe even all of them.